# signalr client not populated angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, signals

I ha have a angularjs directive that will use SignalR.

```
(function(){
  "use strict";

        angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
        .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                var hub = $.connection.realtimeFult;

                $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:39858/signalr";
                $.connection.hub.start();

                hub.client.faultOccured = function (location) {
                    console.log(location);
                };
        }])
        .directive('myCustomer', function() {
          return {
            template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
          };
        });      
})();
```

this does not write browser console anything.

But if I move signalR code out of the directive it writes.

```
(function(){
  "use strict";

        var hub = $.connection.realtimeFult;

        $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:39858/signalr";
        $.connection.hub.start();

        hub.client.faultOccured = function (location) {
            console.log(location);
        };

        angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
        .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        }])
        .directive('myCustomer', function() {
          return {
            template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
          };
        });      
})();
```

this code writes browser console log.

What is the reason of this interesting problem?

Comment: in 1st example I see you use `SignalR ` inside controller, do I miss something?

Comment: Yes first example in controller, 2nd is outside.

Comment: `... But if I move signalR code out of the directive it writes. ...`. hmm

Comment: When I call   `$.connection.hub.start()` after `hub.client.faultOccured` it works in controller. I am using signalR 2.2.2 version. Maybe something changed.